# How to remove a grid point in xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to find the nearest grid point to a weather station given a latitude and longitude. The grid point that is returned when I find the nearest using `df=df.sel(latitude=Lat.to_xarray(), longitude=Lon.to_xarray(), method='nearest')`
is full of Nan values. Because of this I want to find the second nearest grid point in the hopes that it contains data. I'm unsure of how to do that using a modified version of the code above so instead I tried to remove the original grid point returned as the nearest (lat=42.36056, lon=-71.01056) and then rerunning the line above. I tried to remove the point by doing this

```
import os
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

#open gridded data
NUM_DAYS=20
df=xr.open_mfdataset('/glacier1/mmartin/data/ERA5_LandOnly_???????.nc', chunks={'time':24*NUM_DAYS, 'latitude':271, 'longitude':601})

#drop grid point
df=df.drop_sel(latitude=['42.36056'],longitude=['-71.01056'])
```

but when I do this I get the following error: KeyError: "['42.36056'] not found in axis". How can I remove this grid point? Or is there an alternative to find the second nearest grid point? Here is what `print(df)` looks like.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 271, longitude: 601, time: 25933)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1951-01-01 1951-01-02 ... 2021-12-31
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -125.0 -124.9 -124.8 ... -65.2 -65.1 -65.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 50.0 49.9 49.8 49.7 ... 23.3 23.2 23.1 23.0
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 271, 601), meta=np.ndarray>
```

This dataset is not the original data. This is after I found the daily maximum temperature. The original dataset looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 271, longitude: 601, time: 613632)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -125.0 -124.9 -124.8 ... -65.2 -65.1 -65.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 50.0 49.9 49.8 49.7 ... 23.3 23.2 23.1 23.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1951-01-01 ... 2021-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(480, 271, 601), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2022-10-03 03:29:52 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.25.1: /opt/ecmw...
```

I can remove the point ahead of the daily maximum calculation if that works better.

Comment: This dataset is indexed by point and time - so you shouldn’t be able to select lats and lons from it at all. Are you sure this is the original data and not a later step? Also, can you post the result of `print(ds)` as a code block rather than uploading a picture for code/data/errors/etc? Pictures can’t be searched, reformatted, interpreted by screen readers/assistive devices/etc.

Comment: This is the data after I found the daily maximum temperature. I updated the question with print(df) for the original data as well as for the data after I applied `df=df.resample(time='1D').max()` to find the daily maximum temperature

Comment: oh - do the nans vary in time or is it always the same lat/lon pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer to your question, but df.t2m is nan at that latitude and longitude for every time. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I waned to know - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You cannot drop an arbitrary point from the middle of an array. The array is a [hyper]cube, so it's impossible to "remove" a point from the middle of the cube. Instead, if you're trying to extract nearest-non-null-neighbors, you need to set up a custom interpolator to facilitate extracting your data. Luckily, this isn't so bad.

First, find the set of valid points which you want to include in your interpolation. Make sure to stack the data so you can drop any lat/lon combos which have NaNs. Then, use [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) to build a reusable nearest-neighbor interpolation engine, and find the nearest non-null points you want to extract from the array. Once you know which data pixel you want to extract for each station/point, you can extract them from the data using `.sel` (and skip xarray's nearest neighbor lookup entirely).

#### Full Example

**Setup**

I'll set up a quick example dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, xarray as xr, scipy.spatial

lons = np.arange(-109.75, -99.9, 0.5)
lats = np.arange(23.25, 28.01, 0.5)
time = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', freq='D', periods=100)

land_mask = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.random(size=(10, 20)) > 0.3,
    dims=['lat', 'lon'],
    coords=[lats, lons],
)

da = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.random(size=(10, 20, 100)),
    dims=['lat', 'lon', 'time'],
    coords=[lats, lons, time],
).where(land_mask)

ds = xr.Dataset({"t2m": da})
```

And also a DataFrame with "stations" at random locations:

```py
stations = pd.DataFrame({
    'station_id': np.arange(100000, 1000000, 10000),
    'latitude': np.random.random(size=90) * 5 + 23,
    'longitude': np.random.random(size=90) * 10 - 110,
}).set_index("station_id")
```

the data now looks a lot like yours, with a fixed spatial pattern of NaNs and a (large) time dimension:

```py
In [3]: ds
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 10, lon: 20, time: 100)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 23.25 23.75 24.25 24.75 ... 26.25 26.75 27.25 27.75
  * lon      (lon) float64 -109.8 -109.2 -108.8 -108.2 ... -101.2 -100.8 -100.2
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 ... 2020-04-09
Data variables:
    t2m      (lat, lon, time) float64 nan nan nan nan ... 0.9747 0.3858 0.9034
```

and then you want to select the data corresponding to the nearest non-NaN points for a list of points:

```py
In [5]: stations
Out[5]:
             latitude   longitude
station_id
100000      23.547167 -100.674304
110000      23.641703 -108.543307
120000      23.704048 -104.567338
130000      24.858875 -107.999671
140000      24.357413 -102.789371
...               ...         ...
950000      23.879972 -109.887476
960000      25.718888 -107.929292
970000      25.223900 -101.083424
980000      26.847443 -108.199510
990000      24.248193 -103.473922

[90 rows x 2 columns]
```

**Set up interpolation engine**

The first step is to find the set of points which are not NaNs and to stack them so you have a set of valid x and y points to pull from:

```py
In [7]: non_null_points = ds.t2m.notnull().all(dim='time').stack(point=('lat', 'lon'))
   ...: non_null_points = non_null_points.where(non_null_points, drop=True)
   ...: non_null_points
Out[7]:
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (point: 132)>
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
Coordinates:
  * point    (point) MultiIndex
  - lat      (point) float64 23.25 23.25 23.25 23.25 ... 27.75 27.75 27.75 27.75
  - lon      (point) float64 -109.2 -108.8 -107.2 ... -101.8 -100.8 -100.2

In [8]: valid_x = non_null_points.lon.values
   ...: valid_y = non_null_points.lat.values
```

Now, you can use [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) to build a reusable nearest-neighbor interpolation engine:

```py
In [9]: tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(np.stack([valid_x, valid_y]).T)
```

**Query nearest (valid) neighbors using your points**

You can now query this with your station lat and lons, and assign the corresponding nearest valid point back to your stations DataFrame:

```py
In [10]: dist, ind = tree.query(stations[["longitude", "latitude"]].values)

In [11]: stations["nearest_x"] = valid_x[ind]
    ...: stations["nearest_y"] = valid_y[ind]

In [12]: stations
Out[12]:
             latitude   longitude  nearest_x  nearest_y
station_id
100000      23.547167 -100.674304    -100.75      23.75
110000      23.641703 -108.543307    -108.75      23.75
120000      23.704048 -104.567338    -104.75      23.75
130000      24.858875 -107.999671    -108.25      24.75
140000      24.357413 -102.789371    -103.25      24.25
...               ...         ...        ...        ...
950000      23.879972 -109.887476    -109.75      23.75
960000      25.718888 -107.929292    -107.75      25.75
970000      25.223900 -101.083424    -101.25      25.25
980000      26.847443 -108.199510    -108.25      26.75
990000      24.248193 -103.473922    -103.25      24.25

[90 rows x 4 columns]
```

**Reindex the xarray Dataset to conform to your list of points**

Finally, you can use these nearest valid station lat/lons to extract the points from your data:

```py
In [13]: reindexed = ds.sel(lat=stations.nearest_y.to_xarray(), lon=stations.nearest_x.to_xarray())

In [14]: reindexed
Out[14]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (station_id: 90, time: 100)
Coordinates:
    lat         (station_id) float64 23.75 23.75 23.75 ... 25.25 26.75 24.25
    lon         (station_id) float64 -100.8 -108.8 -104.8 ... -108.2 -103.2
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 ... 2020-04-09
  * station_id  (station_id) int64 100000 110000 120000 ... 970000 980000 990000
Data variables:
    t2m         (station_id, time) float64 0.9344 0.6062 ... 0.6152 0.8736
```

Note that the reindexed data does not have any NaNs:

```py
In [15]: reindexed.isnull().any()
Out[15]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    t2m      bool False
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question but I'm having trouble with the scipy part (`tree=scipy.spatial.KDTree(np.stack([valid_x,valid_y]).T)`). How do I import the scipy library? When I do `import scipy` I get a message that spatial does not exist. I then tried `from scipy import spatial` and got "ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity"

Comment: yeah to use `scipy.spatial` you do need to import the subpackage - `import scipy.spatial`, or `from scipy import spatial` as you have. the zero-size array is an unrelated issue - is there a chance `valid_x` and `valid_y` are length zero? I'd take a look at your list of valid points - these should be the same length and not contain any NaNs

Comment: @MeganMartin did you end up getting this to work?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Sorry I didn't post sooner

Comment: great! glad to hear it :)